# .htacces help about allow and deny acces

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, centos

Ok guys.. hello. have a niceday..
My problem is totaly focus on .htacces
for example i have a website : localhost/
and i want for every visitor have deny acces on website for first visit.. on every folder / every photo / everything.
and when they acces a specific link for example: localhost/test.php to allow they ip add the ip in .httacess i think and have acces total on website..

I have something in my mind like.. deny all ips. acces link and receive allow ip and use can use entire website.
and the ip for allow to be take from visitor when acces test.php and the ip going on .htaces with allow
i know this work on denny acces.. but i want on allow acces and only when acces test.php.. if is necesary guys. tell me and i give you the code for denny ip

I hope guys you can understand my problem.. is not hard what i ask but i dont know guys how to put this to work..

PS; localhost is just a example i have a domain. and i want to help me guys with the code on .httaces and maybe if is necesary on test.php

I use apache2 on ubuntu 14 and ubuntu 16

Comment: Certainly that is possible. You will need to use a different domain or better hostname than `localhost` if _others_ are meant to access your site. But apart from that: nothing speaks against what you plan. Start reading the documentation, the apache http server offers an _excellent_ documentation which comes with really good examples. You can do _exactly_ what you want: deny _all_ access to all resources and then add exceptions for specific IP addresses.

Comment: i have domain.. localhost was just a example.. i want something like when acces test.php for example.. the ip go in .httacces and gain allow ip or something like that

Comment: Sure, we understood that. I told you how to proceed. What you ask is documented. You just need to start reading the documentation of the tools you use. Why don't you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way in .htaccess

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <ip to access permited> //allow from 255.0.0.0
```

Comment: i dont want to put manualy the ip.. i want something like when acces test.php for example.. the ip go in .httacces and gain allow ip or something like that

Comment: It's a big security risk to add dynamically. Its really not recommend to allow php to add anything into .htaccess.

//You can try this code
$f = fopen(".htaccess", "a+");
fwrite($f, "<content here>");
fclose($f);